# Getting unique data from table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to get all the last messages that user A had with his other friends.

I have a table friend and message

friend table is as follows

```
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user1   | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user2   | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pending | tinyint(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

message table is as follows

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id              | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| sender          | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| receiver        | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| message         | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| message_read    | tinyint(1)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| message_visible | int(6)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| message_date    | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Here is profile table

```
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nickname | varchar(50)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image    | mediumblob      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As requested, here is the data set of message

```
+----+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | sender | receiver | message                                                     | message_read | message_visible | message_date        |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
|  2 |      1 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:16 |
|  3 |      2 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-29 21:10:15 |
|  4 |      2 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
|  5 |      1 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
|  6 |      1 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
|  7 |      4 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-29 21:10:15 |
|  8 |      4 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:17 |
|  9 |      5 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:18 |
| 10 |      5 |        1 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 11 |      1 |        5 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
| 12 |      1 |        5 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 13 |      1 |        7 | test                                                        |            1 |               7 | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 14 |      2 |        3 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 15 |      2 |        3 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
| 16 |      3 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:17 |
| 17 |      3 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 18 |      3 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 19 |      3 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
| 20 |      4 |        3 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:17 |
| 21 |      4 |        3 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 22 |      2 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 23 |      2 |        4 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:14 |
| 24 |      4 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:17 |
| 25 |      4 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2017-09-30 21:10:15 |
| 26 |     11 |        4 | test1                                                       |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-19 13:24:53 |
| 27 |     11 |        6 | test2                                                       |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-19 19:56:46 |
| 28 |     11 |        7 | test3                                                       |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-19 12:30:38 |
| 29 |      4 |       11 | test1_response                                              |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-19 21:03:27 |
| 30 |      6 |       11 | test2_response                                              |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-19 21:03:34 |
| 31 |     13 |        6 | test1                                                       |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-20 09:36:09 |
| 32 |     13 |        7 | test1                                                       |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-20 09:36:13 |
| 33 |     11 |       13 | test11                                                      |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-20 09:36:21 |
| 34 |     13 |       11 | test11_response                                             |            1 |            NULL | 2017-10-20 09:41:27 |
| 35 |   1013 |        2 | test                                                        |            1 |            NULL | 2018-03-29 13:35:31 |
| 36 |      2 |     1013 | Longer text message test, and I wish this works beautifully |            1 |            NULL | 2018-03-29 15:12:33 |
| 37 |   1013 |        2 | Longer text message test, and I wish this works beautifully |            1 |            NULL | 2018-03-29 15:17:40 |
| 38 |   1013 |        2 | Longer text message test, and I wish this works beautifully |            1 |            NULL | 2018-03-29 15:41:55 |
| 39 |   1015 |        2 | What's up                                                   |            1 |            NULL | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 |
| 40 |      2 |     1015 | What up?                                                    |            1 |            NULL | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 |
| 42 |      2 |     1015 | What's up                                                   |            0 |            NULL | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Below is the data set of friend

```
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
| id  | user1 | user2 | pending |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
|   1 |     1 |     2 |       0 |
|   3 |     1 |     5 |       0 |
|   4 |     6 |     1 |       0 |
|   6 |     2 |     5 |       0 |
|   7 |     3 |     5 |       0 |
|   8 |     6 |     2 |       0 |
|   9 |     6 |     1 |       0 |
|  10 |     5 |     4 |       0 |
|  11 |     4 |     1 |       0 |
|  12 |     1 |     7 |       1 |
|  19 |    12 |     1 |       1 |
|  20 |    12 |     2 |       0 |
|  22 |    12 |     4 |       0 |
|  23 |    12 |    11 |       0 |
|  25 |     6 |    11 |       0 |
|  26 |     7 |    11 |       0 |
|  27 |     7 |    12 |       0 |
|  28 |     6 |    13 |       0 |
|  29 |     7 |    13 |       0 |
|  30 |    11 |    13 |       0 |
|  31 |  1013 |     2 |       0 |
|  39 |  1015 |     2 |       0 |
| 104 |  1015 |  1021 |       1 |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
```

Below is snippet of profile data

```
+------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
| id   | user_id | nickname | email | image |
+------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
|    1 |       1 | user1    |       | NULL  |
|    2 |       2 | user2    | NULL  | NULL  |
|    3 |       3 | user3    | NULL  | NULL  |
|    4 |       4 | user4    | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1014 |    1018 | user1019 | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1015 |    1019 | user1020 | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1016 |    1020 | user1021 | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1017 |    1021 | user1022 | NULL  | NULL  |
+------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I coded out my statement referencing some great answers posted on StackOverFlow

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT msg.message, msg.message_read, msg.message_date,   
CASE WHEN msg.receiver = 1013  
THEN (SELECT nickname FROM profile WHERE user_id = msg.sender) 
ELSE (SELECT nickname FROM profile WHERE user_id = msg.receiver) 
END AS name, 

CASE WHEN msg.receiver = 1013 
THEN (SELECT image FROM profile WHERE user_id = msg.sender)  
ELSE (SELECT image FROM profile WHERE user_id = msg.receiver)  
END AS image  

FROM message msg  
JOIN  
(SELECT user, max(message_date) m  
FROM  
((SELECT id, receiver user, message_date FROM message WHERE sender = 1015 AND (message_visible =1 OR message_visible IS NULL))  
UNION  
(SELECT id, sender user, message_date FROM message WHERE receiver = 1015 AND (message_visible =1 OR message_visible IS NULL))) m1 GROUP BY user) m2 ON  
((sender = 1015 AND receiver = user) OR (sender = user AND receiver = 1015)) AND (message_date = m) ORDER BY message_date desc;
```

The result I get is

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| message   | message_read | message_date        | name     | image |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| What's up |            1 | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 | user2    | NULL  |
| What up?  |            1 | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 | user1016 | NULL  |
| What's up |            0 | 2018-04-17 16:33:29 | user1016 | NULL  |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

I would like to get only one of these.. It does not really matter which one. Of course, there are going to be more messages if there are more users. The problem is when I have same message_date. Although it seems implausible to have message sent at the same time, I would at least want to learn how to control this situation.

Comment: where you get user name?

Comment: where is the **profile** table ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I updated the profile table

Comment: Please add a data set. Ok our result but it's important too the data set

Comment: @JoeTaras I just added a data set. Profile just holds the name of each user, so I did not add this data set

Comment: You should add profile otherwise you will get a different result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your get the messages from your userA with anyone else. I didnt include the condition for when message arent visible because the logic wasnt clear from the question. You will have to add it yourself.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d506e/10)** (without profile table)

```
SELECT m.message, 
       m.message_read,
       m.message_date,
       CASE WHEN m.sender = @userA_ID
            THEN m.receiver
            ELSE m.sender
       END as friend_id,           
       CASE WHEN m.sender = @userA_ID
            THEN p2.nickname
            ELSE p1.nickname
       END as name,
       CASE WHEN m.sender = @userA_ID
            THEN p2.image
            ELSE p1.image
       END as image
FROM message as m
JOIN profile as p1
  ON m.sender = p1.user_id    -- sender
JOIN profile as p2 
  ON m.receiver = p1.user_id  -- receiver
WHERE @userA_ID IN (m.sender, m.receiver)
```

Now you use variables to order the message by friend and date, notice you use `friend_id` in case two friends have the same name.

```
SELECT t.*,
       @rn := if(@friend = t.friend_id, 
                 @rn + 1,
                 if( @friend := t.friend_id, 1, 1)
                ) as rn
FROM ( ** previous_query ** ) as t
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @friend := 0 ) as var
ORDER BY t.friend_id, t.message_date desc
```

notice you can add another condition to order to handle ties when same date

Finally you filter the message with `rn = 1`

```
SELECT *
FROM ( ** second query **) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi, I am using Java to handle this data. I am not sure how to have multiple statements. Would it be possible to put all together in one statement? Message_visible is an indicator that shows who can look at the message. If it is null both parties can look at the message. Otherwise, only the indicated person can see the message. It just safeguards that the user who deleted the message cannot retrieve it again.

Comment: Yes, Just put the previous query inside the parenthesis. I split it so is easy to understand. But first you should test it inside mysql to see if is working as desire

Comment: check my edit. I add a demo using your sample data. Without profile

Comment: Holy moly! That works just beautifully. Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Hi Juan Carlos Oropeza, thanks a lot for your great help. I just have one more quick question on this. Is there a way to reduce the scope into only friends? I have a query here that gets only friends: SELECT CASE WHEN user1 = (user_id) THEN user2 ELSE user1 END AS friend FROM friend WHERE (user1 = 2 OR user2 = 2) AND pending = 0; I am just trying to figure out a way to include nickname and image data from profile into the query you just created for my question. Thanks again for your great help!!!

Comment: do you need check for friend? can you send message to non friends?

Comment: Nope. I made it so that messages can only be sent between friends for this specific one. I am thinking about changing friend table so that it is easier to get friend list because I believe it is not that great as of now.

Comment: I dont see how could you improve that. That is how I would do it. Do you need anything else?

Comment: Okay okay that sounds great. I just need to retrieve image and nickname from profile in that same query that you created. Inside of (message, message_read, message_date, friend_id, rn) that your query gets, I just need to get nickname and image from profile using friend_id. Simply, select nickname, image from profile where friend_id = user_id; I just do not know how to include this within your query. Really appreciate your great help!!

Comment: ok, no problem. I would do it that time but you forgot add the profile table at that momement

Comment: Oh haha sorry.. I thought I could just swap it in and everything will work as expected. Well, it was a mistake :(

Comment: check sql demo.

Comment: I don't think the link provided in your answer up there is updated yet. Can you please share another link?

Comment: please try again. Remember change `m.sender = 1` for `m.sender = @yourSearchID`

Comment: OH LORD!!! IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM. I am so very much grateful for your gracious help!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH~~~~ Saved my life.